# faster way to scatter multiple image items html

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm new to animating and im currently trying to achieve this look below: however because I want to animate these stars to wiggle when you hover over them and I figured out I need to manually insert each star rather than just inserting this whole picture. Is there a faster/more efficient way to go about this? Should I write an insert js function for this? 
Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: `Should I write an insert js function for this` - yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 pictures with the same position of stars.
The first picture is this one and the second picture with brighter stars, then alternate them in a short period of time.

```js
setInterval(function(){
 $('img').prop('src', 'https://preview.ibb.co/kfbsWk/kpme4_brighter.png');
}, 200);

setTimeout(function(){
 setInterval(function(){
  $('img').prop('src', 'https://preview.ibb.co/fSHzBk/kpme4.png');
 }, 200);
 }, 100
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://ibb.co/evgRrk"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/fSHzBk/kpme4.png" alt="kpme4" border="0"></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://vi.imgbb.com/'>image host</a><br />
```

Comment: I wanted the stars to wiggle when you hover over them, sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: Then you definitely need Js.

Comment: Add stars randomly to the page, attach the hover event to those stars and each time you hover the image, change the star image to the appropriate one (brighter or rotated angle).

Answer (score 4):

You probably need [Particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/)

> A lightweight JavaScript library for creating particles.

---

The usage is simple.

1. Load the library from a CDN or locally. I used

   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>`
2. create a container for the particles with `id="particles-js"`
3. style it like so:

   `#particles-js {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     overflow: hidden;
   }`
4. Go to [the official page](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) and set whatever settings you want
5. export settings as json
6. Add json contents in a `<script>` tag in your document.

Responsive interactive demo:

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 200,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "star",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 35,
        "height": 35
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.35,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": .5,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 4,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": false,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.1,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": .5,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": true,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": true,
        "rotateX": 4024.6529723245903,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "bubble"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 150,
        "size": 5,
        "duration": 8,
        "opacity": .2,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 100,
        "duration": 5
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#particles-js {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stars,
.twinkle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: -10;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyeSl.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.twinkle {
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Sz6.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: stars 1000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes stars {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

<div id="particles-js"></div>
<div class="stars"></div>
<div class="twinkle"></div>
```

If prefer something non-interactive as that probably has much better overall performance a much simpler version can be achieved Like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.stars,
.twinkle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: -10;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyeSl.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.twinkle {
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Sz6.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: stars 1000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes stars {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stars"></div>
<div class="twinkle"></div>
```

---

Note: Small stars in the background *shamelessly* stolen from [a pen by Annaliza Torres](https://codepen.io/aptorres27/pen/mPGZPp)